# Segregate parts a string based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to segregate singles, doubles and triples from a string.

e.g. (2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 - 11 , 12 - 14 , 15 - 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 - 22 , 23 - 25 , 26 , 27 , 28 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 35 , 36 , 37 , 38 , 39 , 40)

Result should be

**Singles** - (2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ,17 , 18 , 19 , 20 ,26 , 27 , 28 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 35 , 36 , 37 , 38 , 39 , 40)

**Doubles** - (10 - 11 ,15 - 16 , 21 - 22 )

**Triples** - (12 - 14 ,23 - 25 )

Comment: Do you have some code for us to advise on?

Comment: @vincrichaud I have multiple PDF Pages like (500 to 1000 nos), I want to give print all of them. but singles should be print individual pages, Doubles should be print with both side print on one page only and triples should be print individually. so when i take print all pages not arrangement properly and for that i ask help to get rid of paper waste. extremely thankful if get solve this. Please see image how i take them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub x()

Dim s As String
Dim a() As String
Dim a2() As String
Dim v As Variant
Dim colSingles As New Collection
Dim colDoubles As New Collection
Dim colTriples As New Collection

s = "2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 - 11 , 12 - 14 , 15 - 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 - 22 , 23 - 25 , 26 , 27 , 28 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 35 , 36 , 37 , 38 , 39 , 40"
a = Split(s, ",")

For Each v In a

    If InStr(1, v, "-") = 0 Then
        colSingles.Add v, CStr(v)
    Else
        a2 = Split(v, "-")
        If a2(1) - a2(0) = 1 Then
            colDoubles.Add v, CStr(v)
        Else
            colTriples.Add v, CStr(v)
        End If
    End If

Next v


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanxx @Nathan_Sav for clarification , As mention in question i want to write in excel Singles - (2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ,17 , 18 , 19 , 20 ,26 , 27 , 28 , 29 , 30 , 31 , 32 , 33 , 34 , 35 , 36 , 37 , 38 , 39 , 40)

Doubles - (10 - 11 ,15 - 16 , 21 - 22 )

Triples - (12 - 14 ,23 - 25 )